# Centered, multiline text using iTextSharp ColumnText

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

I am trying to center a block of multiline text using iTextSharp. I thought that using the ColumnText would do the trick, but I'm having some trouble getting both center alignment, as well as proper wrapping working at the same time.

Here is some code which shows the 2 methods I'm trying:

```
private void PrintLocationAddress(PdfContentByte Canvas, string Address)
{
    //define the regions for our ColumnText objects
    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(150f, 300, 350f, 450f);
    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(150f, 50f, 350f, 200f);

    //outline the rectangles so we can visualize placement of the ColumnText
    Canvas.Rectangle(rect1.Left, rect1.Bottom, rect1.Width, rect1.Height);
    Canvas.Rectangle(rect2.Left, rect2.Bottom, rect2.Width, rect2.Height);
    Canvas.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.CYAN);
    Canvas.Stroke();

    //define the text and style
    Chunk c = new Chunk(Address, new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.MAGENTA));
    c.SetTextRenderMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL, 0, BaseColor.PINK);
    Phrase LongText = new Phrase(c);

    //this text is centered, but will wrap onto itself on the same line
    ColumnText column1 = new ColumnText(Canvas);
    column1.SetSimpleColumn(LongText, rect1.Left, rect1.Bottom, rect1.Right, rect1.Top, 0, PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER);
    column1.Go();

    //this text will wrap, but how to center it?!
    ColumnText column2 = new ColumnText(Canvas);
    column2.SetSimpleColumn(rect2);
    column2.SetText(LongText);
    column2.Go();
}
```

You can view the output for the above code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7vRQ.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the ColumnText.Alignment property:

```
column2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
```

So, to get Multiline text, centered, in a box of specified dimensions using ColumnText:

```
ColumnText column2 = new ColumnText(Canvas);
column2.SetSimpleColumn(rect2);
column2.SetText(LongText);
column2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
column2.Go();
```