# Can I assign HTML to a Paragraph in iTextSharp rather than concatenating Chunks?

Tags: html, pdf-generation, itext, paragraph, chunks

I need to write a paragraph to a PDF file I'm generating. Said paragraph is comprised of a bolded first word in red, some "regular" red text after that, then a link (blue), some more regular red text, and finally another link (also blue). I think I can use Chunks to do that, something like this (pseudocode):

```
Chunk boldChunk = new Chunk("Important:"); // add font via GetFont?
boldChunk.SetBold();
boldChunk.SetColor(red);

Chunk beginChunk = new Chunk("Form must be filled out in ");
beginChunk.SetColor(red);

Chunk underlinedAdobeReader = new Chunk("Adobe Reader");
underlinedAdobeReader.SetUnderline(0.5f, -1.5f);
underlinedAdobeReader.SetColor(blue);
underlinedAdobeReader.SetHRef("http://www.adobe.com");

Chunk middleChunk = new Chunk("or Acrobat Professional 
8.1 or above. To save completed forms, Acrobat Professional is required. For 
technical and accessibility assistance, contact the ");
middleChunk.SetColor(red);

Chunk underlinedJefe = new Chunk("Chief Platypus");
underlinedJefe.SetUnderline(0.5f, -1.5f);
underlinedJefe.SetColor(blue);
underlinedJefe.SetHref("http://twaincentral.azurewebsites.net/");

doc.Add(boldChunk);
doc.Add(beginChunk);
doc.Add(underlinedJefe);
doc.Add(middleChunk);
doc.Add(underlinedCampusOffice);
```

....but that seems borderline outlandish; Is there a way I can "cut to the chase" and assign some HTML to the doc, as in:

```
String composite = "<strong>Important:</strong> Form must be filled out in <a href="http://www.adobe.com" target="_blank">Adobe Reader</a> 
or Acrobat Professional 
8.1 or above. To save completed forms, Acrobat Professional is required. For 
technical and accessibility assistance, contact the <a href="http://twaincentral.azurewebsites.net/" target="_blank">Chief Platypus</a>");
doc.Add(composite);
```

I also want to restrict this paragraph to West of the Mississippi (that is to say, the left half of the page), but that is a [separate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525650/how-can-i-restrict-the-width-of-a-paragraph-on-a-pdf-page-using-itextsharp).

Comment: If your HTML is very simple you could [try something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8327462/231316)

Comment: I'll try that, but how complex is too complex? My HTML (shown at the end of my post above) contains a strong and two anchor tags. Come to think of it, I also need the text to be red (other than the links/hrefs). I guess I could use spans with inline color styles set...

Comment: That example uses the `HTMLWorker` which is obsolete and doesn't support much (if any) CSS. Honestly, you'll just need to see if it works with your code. If it doesn't, then I'd try [switching to `XmlWorker`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25164258/231316) which should get you want you want.

Comment: I find it odd that XMLWorker (apparently) supports CSS more fully than HTMLWorker does.

Comment: Why is that odd? `HTMLWorker` grew organically and is full of *spaghetti code* (it was impossible to further maintain it). XML Worker was built from scratch with the specific goal to be a generic XML tool, with XHTML as the format of choice to test the functionality.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: It seems odd to me because when I think of CSS, I think of it being married to HTML, not XML.